# Picasso loading the same image in every row in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, picasso, android-image

I am using a viewHolder pattern with two images, the profile pic and video thumbnail. On every row, the video thumbnail is fine, but the profile pic is the same one, it keeps reloading the same picture even though it's a different link. 
I tried to cancel request using picasso but nothing changes. I know I'm missing like one line somewhere, I tried quite a few things but nothing.

```
   @Override
    public View getView(int position, View rowView, ViewGroup parent) {
        viewHolder = null;

        if (rowView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            rowView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, parent, false);

            viewHolder.titleTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.usernameinlist);
            viewHolder.timeago = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.timeago);
            viewHolder.sharebutton = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.sharebutton);
            viewHolder.likesTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.likestext);
            viewHolder.viewcount = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.viewcount);
            viewHolder.distance = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.distance);
            viewHolder.footprints = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.footprintcount);

//            Picasso.with(mContext).cancelRequest(viewHolder.profilePic);
            viewHolder.profilePic = (CircleImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.profilethumb);
            viewHolder.caption = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.captiontext);
            viewHolder.moremenu = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.dots);
            viewHolder.likesPic = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.likeimage);
            viewHolder.mapitPic = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.mapimage);

            viewHolder.itemView = rowView;
            viewHolder.setBackgroundImage((ParallaxImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.videothumb));

            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }

        post = (Post) getItem(position);

        viewHolder.profilePic.setOnItemSelectedClickListener(this);
        viewHolder.titleTextView.setText(post.getUsername().toUpperCase());
        PrettyTime prettyTime = new PrettyTime();
        DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(post.getUploadDate().get$date());
        viewHolder.timeago.setText(prettyTime.format(dateTime.toDate()).toUpperCase());
        viewHolder.likesTextView.setText(String.valueOf(format(post.getLikes())));
        viewHolder.footprints.setText(String.valueOf(format(post.getLocation().size() - 1)));
        double[] loc = post.getLocation().get(0);
        viewHolder.distance.setText("~" + PostListFragment.distance(loc[0], loc[1], 'M') + " MILES AWAY");
        if (post.getViews() != null)
            viewHolder.viewcount.setText(format(post.getViews()) + (post.getViews() == 1 ? " VIEW" : " VIEWS"));

        String profilePictureS3Url = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/moleheadphotos/" + post.getUsername()
                + ".jpg";

        String filename = post.getS3link();  // function?????????
        String videoThumbURL = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/moleheadphotos/" + filename;

        Picasso.with(mContext).load(videoThumbURL).into(viewHolder.getBackgroundImage());
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(profilePictureS3Url).into(viewHolder.profilePic);
        viewHolder.getBackgroundImage().setParallaxRatio(0.9f);
```

### UPDATE

console logs different values for post.getUsername()

`12-13 02:01:30.701 28887-28887/? D/profilePicUrl: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/moleheadphotos/frankenstein.jpg
12-13 02:01:30.761 28887-28887/? D/profilePicUrl: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/moleheadphotos/obody.jpg
12-13 02:01:30.861 28887-28887/? D/profilePicUrl: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/moleheadphotos/obody.jpg
12-13 02:01:30.891 28887-28887/? D/profilePicUrl: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/moleheadphotos/obody.jpg
12-13 02:01:43.031 28887-28887/? D/profilePicUrl: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/moleheadphotos/obody.jpg
12-13 02:01:43.181 28887-28887/? D/profilePicUrl: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/moleheadphotos/frankenstein.jpg
12-13 02:01:43.481 28887-28887/? D/profilePicUrl: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/moleheadphotos/frankenstein.jpg
12-13 02:01:47.591 28887-28887/? D/profilePicUrl: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/moleheadphotos/kdelva.jpg`

Comment: Please past your getItem(int position) method

Comment: @Kelevandos ```public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mDataSource.get(position);
    }```

Comment: In the question please, the comments do not have code formatting :-) Ok then, what is the mDataSource? And what is the code in it's get(int position)?

Comment: @Kelevandos that's standard android code, not part of the problem

Comment: Are you sure the url is always different? It is generated using the Post object, so the problem could be the Object being always the same

Comment: @Kelevandos no, the object is different. I even tap on the video and it's a different one every time. The video thumbnail is different, but profilePic is the same on every row

Comment: Please create a breakpoint/debug log and check if post.getUsername() returns different value each time

Comment: @Kelevandos checked, logged and prints different value, the value is correct see update

Comment: bug in CircleImageView

Comment: pls try adding the profilePicUrl to viewHolder.getBackgroundImage() piccaso line